# Undefined index with $_POST function

Tags: php, mysql, post

So I Basically copied the following code, execpt renaming columns names.

The form is folowing:

```
<table align="left" width="30%" border="0" >
<form action="company_edit_php.php" method="post">
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ECE6E6">Location: <td align="center"> <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Location']?>"/><br></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ECE6E6">User: <td align="center">  <input type="text" value="<?php  echo $row['User']?>"/><br></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ECE6E6">Telephone: <td align="center">  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Telephone']?>"/><br></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ECE6E6">Email: <td align="center">  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Email']?>"/><br></td></tr>
<td> <input type="submit" value="Change" /></td></tr>
```

And PHP code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id']: 1;
mysql_select_db("Database", $con);

if (isset($_POST['Location'])) {
    echo $_POST['Location'];
 } else {
    echo 'empty';
 } 

$Location = $_POST['Location'];
```

Result of this code is Undefined index: Location and from if statement i get "empty".
Why this same code work for another page? What should I do now?

Thank you for your efforts

Comment: show us the complete form in html please

Comment: Is there a field named location in your form?

Comment: Giving the whole form would be helpful, yes.

Comment: Are you ***actually*** posting a field called "Location"?

Answer (score 2):

To correct the index post, use this command at the beginning of the file and uses the variable `$Location`

```
$Location = (isset($_POST["Location"])?$_POST["Location"]:"");
```

Comment: This may only help him avoid getting a null variable, not getting the correct value. Plus he uses `$_POST`

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your form because you miss `name` into your input and to retrieve the value with `$_GET` you have to use it like this:

```
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ECE6E6">Location: <td align="center"> <input type="text" name="Location" value="<?php echo $row['Location']?>"/><br></td></tr>
```

Comment: pretty fast. This is the problem (and I guess the poster didn't use this exact form, if it worked in another place)

Comment: Yes you're right i somehow missed "name" into my form. It works now!

Comment: @user1758545 accept the answer if you have solved the problem please

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of textboxes, you need to give them name

```
<table align="left" width="30%" border="0" >
    <form action="company_edit_php.php" method="post">
    <tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ECE6E6">Location: <td align="center"> <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Location']?>" name='location'/><br></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ECE6E6">User: <td align="center">  <input type="text" value="<?php  echo $row['User']?>" name='user'/><br></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ECE6E6">Telephone: <td align="center">  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Telephone']?>" name='phone'/><br></td></tr>
    <tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ECE6E6">Email: <td align="center">  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Email']?>" name='mail'/><br></td></tr>
    <td> <input type="submit" value="Change" /></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id']: 1;
mysql_select_db("Database", $con);


$location= "";

if (isset($_POST['Location'])) {
    $location= $_POST['Location']; // <-------------    put this here!
    //echo $_POST['Location'];
 } else {
    echo 'empty';
 } 

 echo $location; // <-------------   added this


 //$Location = $_POST['Location'];  // it was erroring here as I am guessing that you were sometimes accessing the page without posting the location. If the variable does not exist, you cannot echo it.. thus the changes above
```

Comment: else part also requires $location variable, i guess

Comment: Not really, since it's set to empty above the `if` clause. ;)

Comment: Hit refresh - I have edited it - to make more sence! As smott said the $location variable has been initialised above so there is no chance of you echoing a variable that does not exist as before

Answer (score 0):

`Location` is not passed in the code that you show.  for that reason `$_POST['Location']` is undefined.  put it inside your if statement to avoid the error.

like:

```
$Location = 'empty';
if (isset($_POST['Location'])) {
    echo $_POST['Location'];
    $Location = $_POST['Location'];
 } else {
    echo 'empty';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete form

```
<table align="left" width="30%" border="0" >
<form action="company_edit_php.php" method="post">
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ECE6E6">Location: <td align="center"> <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Location']?>"/><br></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ECE6E6">User: <td align="center">  <input type="text" value="<?php  echo $row['User']?>"/><br></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ECE6E6">Telephone: <td align="center">  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Telephone']?>"/><br></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#ECE6E6">Email: <td align="center">  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Email']?>"/><br></td></tr>
<td> <input type="submit" value="Change" /></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you are writing it is so that either there is no field named "Location" on the page you made, or it is outside of the form  (thus not inside ....).
As it works on the site  where the original sourcecode has been taken from there are only 2 options there.

1. The site in question HAS a field named location inside the appropriate form
2. The site in question suppresses the error message that would come.

In order for your code to work you would need to 1.) put the field "Location" inside the form if it is not already  and 2.) You need to "secure" the getting of the variable so that an error is not shown even if Location is empty.
I'm giving different examples for both variants:
1.) Putting Location inside the form

```
<form action="company_edit.php" method="post">
......
<input type="text" name="Location" id="Location>
......
</form>
```

2.) Making sure that the error does not occur even if Location does notee xist,....
    I would even advice doing the following step for every $_POST and $_GET variable you want
    to use in your application as it reduces the chance of the error message that a specific
    $_GET/$_POST is not set considerably (although for debugging and finding writing errors
    it is good to have the error messages).

```
if (isset($_POST['Location'])
     $Location = $_POST['Location'];
else
     $Location='';
```

---

On another note as you are giving parameters via POST and you don't put the id into the URL the $_GET of id will always result in an empty id field (thus the "1" is always used as id). For it to work you would either need to use id as post and put an appropriate field into the form or you would have to eidt the "action" part of the form so that id is given as "?id=" parameter there